# Manipulating tab-delimited text files in Python

Tags: python

I would appreciate any example code on how to tackle the question:

I am presented with tab-delimited text files, A and B.

File A has multiple columns of alpha-numeric codes that are in a deprecated format.

File B has 2 columns: the first column has the deprecated codes from File A, the second column has the modern versions of the deprecated codes. In other words, File B "translates" between the deprecated codes and the modern codes.

The task is to write a script that 1) converts the deprecated codes in File A to the modern codes, 2) writes the output to a new tab-delimited text file, and 3) in the new file modifies the order of the columns to differ from the order of the columns in File A.

For task 1, I am allowed to use arrays or hashes. While I know hashes are likely more efficient for task 1, I have limited familiarity with hashes and prefer to use arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read both files.

For File B create a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) with the first field as the key and the second field as the value. As you go through File A you can do a direct lookup and substitution using the dictionary.

Comment: For clarification, I believe that the `hashes` requirement would be met by a `dictionary` in your case, zhaoy.